# Rendering using normal maps causes rotation-dependent lighting

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

The normal mapping looks great when the objects aren't rotated from the origin, and spot lights and directional lights work, but when I spin an object on the spot it darkens and then lightens again, just on the top face.

I'm testing using a cube. I've used a geometry shader to visualise my calculated normals (after multiplying by a TBN matrix), and they appear to be in the correct places. If I take the normal map out of the equation then the lighting is fine.

Here's where the TBN is calculated:

```
void calculateTBN()
{
    //get the normal matrix
    mat3 model = mat3(transpose(inverse(mat3(transform))));
    vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * tangent.xyz ));

    vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * normal      ));

    vec3 B = cross(N, T);

    mat3 TBN = mat3( T , B , N);

    outputVertex.TBN =TBN;
}
```

And the normal is sampled and transformed:

```
vec3 calculateNormal()
{
    //Sort the input so that the normal is between 1 and minus 1 instead of 0 and 1
    vec3 input = texture2D(normalMap, inputFragment.textureCoord).xyz;

    input = 2.0 * input - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    vec3 newNormal = normalize(inputFragment.TBN* input);

    return newNormal;
}
```

My Lighting is in world space (as far as I understand the term, it takes into account the transform matrix but not the camera or projection matrix)

I did try the technique where I pass down the TBN as inverse (or transpose) and then multiplied every vector apart from the normal by it. That had the same effect. I'd rather work in world space anyway as apparently this is better for deffered lighting? Or so I've heard.

If you'd like to see any of the lighting code and so on I'll add it in but I didn't think it was necessary as it works apart from this.

EDIT::
As requested, here is vertex and part of frag shader

```
    #version 330


uniform mat4 T; // Translation matrix
uniform mat4 S; // Scale matrix
uniform mat4 R; // Rotation matrix
uniform mat4 camera; // camera matrix
uniform vec4 posRelParent; // the position relative to the parent


// Input vertex packet
layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 tangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 bitangent;
layout (location = 8) in vec2 textureCoord;


// Output vertex packet
out packet {

    vec2 textureCoord;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 vert;
    mat3 TBN;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 bitangent;
    vec3 normalTBN;

} outputVertex;

mat4 transform;
mat3 TBN;

void calculateTBN()
{
    //get the model matrix, the transform of the object with scaling and transform  removeds
    mat3 model = mat3(transpose(inverse(transform)));

    vec3 T = normalize(model*tangent.xyz);

    vec3 N = normalize(model*normal);

    //I used to retrieve the bitangents by crossing the normal and tangent but now they are calculated independently
    vec3 B = normalize(model*bitangent.xyz);

    TBN = mat3( T , B , N);

    outputVertex.TBN = TBN;

    //Pass though TBN vectors for colour debugging in the fragment shader
    outputVertex.tangent = T;
    outputVertex.bitangent = B;
    outputVertex.normalTBN = N;


}

void main(void) {
    outputVertex.textureCoord = textureCoord;


    // Setup local variable pos in case we want to modify it (since position is constant)
    vec4 pos = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0) + posRelParent;

    //Work out the transform matrix
    transform = T * R * S;

//Work out the normal for lighting
    mat3 normalMat = transpose(inverse(mat3(transform)));

    outputVertex.normal = normalize(normalMat* normal);

    calculateTBN();

    outputVertex.vert =(transform* pos).xyz;

    //Work out the final pos of the vertex
    gl_Position = camera * transform * pos;
    }
```

And Lighting vector of fragment:

```
vec3 applyLight(Light thisLight, vec3 baseColor, vec3 surfacePos, vec3 surfaceToCamera)
{
    float attenuation = 1.0f;
    vec3 lightPos = (thisLight.finalLightMatrix*thisLight.position).xyz;
    vec3 surfaceToLight;

    vec3 coneDir = normalize(thisLight.coneDirection);

    if (thisLight.position.w == 0.0f)
    {
        //Directional Light (all rays same angle, use position as direction)
        surfaceToLight = normalize( (thisLight.position).xyz);
        attenuation = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        //Point light
        surfaceToLight = normalize(lightPos - surfacePos);


        float distanceToLight = length(lightPos - surfacePos);
        attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0f + thisLight.attenuation * pow(distanceToLight, 2));

        //Work out the Cone restrictions
        float lightToSurfaceAngle = degrees(acos(dot(-surfaceToLight, normalize(coneDir))));

        if (lightToSurfaceAngle > thisLight.coneAngle)
        {
            attenuation = 0.0;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the main of the frag shader too:

```
void main(void) {
    //get the base colour from the texture
    vec4 tempFragColor = texture2D(textureImage, inputFragment.textureCoord).rgba;

    //Support for objects with and without a normal map
    if (useNormalMap == 1)
    {  
        calcedNormal = calculateNormal();
    }
    else
    {
        calcedNormal = inputFragment.normal;

    }


    vec3 surfaceToCamera = normalize((cameraPos_World) - (inputFragment.vert));

    vec3 tempColour = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    for (int count = 0; count < numLights; count++)
    {
        tempColour += applyLight(allLights[count], tempFragColor.xyz, inputFragment.vert, surfaceToCamera);
    }


    vec3 gamma = vec3(1.0 / 2.2);

    fragmentColour = vec4(pow(tempColour,gamma), tempFragColor.a);
    //fragmentColour = vec4(calcedNormal, 1);
}
```

Edit 2:

The geometry shader used to visualize "sampled" normals by the TBN matrix as shown here:

[image]

```
void GenerateLineAtVertex(int index)
{
    vec3 testSampledNormal = vec3(0, 0, 1);

    vec3 bitangent = cross(gs_in[index].normal, gs_in[index].tangent);

    mat3 TBN = mat3(gs_in[index].tangent, bitangent, gs_in[index].normal);

    testSampledNormal = TBN * testSampledNormal;


    gl_Position = gl_in[index].gl_Position;

    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position =
         gl_in[index].gl_Position 
        +  vec4(testSampledNormal, 0.0) * MAGNITUDE;


    EmitVertex();


    EndPrimitive();
}
```

And it's vertex shader

```
void main(void) {

// Setup local variable pos in case we want to modify it (since position is constant)
vec4 pos = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);

mat4 transform = T* R * S;

// Apply transformation to pos and store result in gl_Position
gl_Position = projection* camera* transform * pos;


mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(camera * transform)));
vs_out.tangent = normalize(vec3(projection * vec4(normalMatrix * tangent.xyz, 0.0)));
vs_out.normal =  normalize(vec3(projection * vec4(normalMatrix * normal     , 0.0)));
}
```

Here is the TBN vectors visualized. The slight angles on the points are due to an issue with how I'm applying the projection matrix, rather than mistakes in the actual vectors. The red lines just show where the arrows I've drawn on the texture are, they're not very clear from that angle that's all.

[image: TBN vectors]

Comment: There is lot's of weird stuff in your code. The normals in the model as visualized in the GS output picture are broken, but that is either an issue with the model or the loader. Why do you multiply the tangent by the inverse-transpose of the`model` matrix? That doesn't make sense geometrically. Your  orthogonality assumptions on the TBN vectors do not hold true, and you also do not propely re-normalize the vectors in the FS.

Comment: Also, you never tried to debug the `T` and `B` vectors, and "multiply a "fake sampled normal" by the TBN matrix and display either, and they show the same thing if the fake normal is 0,0,1" only proves that matrix multiplication works. It does not test the TB components at all.

Comment: I have debugged the T and B vectors, and to my knowledge they look correct. The GS output picture is 0,0,1 multiplied by the TBN matrix and they look fine to me, identical to the result of visualising the normals, what looks off to you?

I read in a tutorial that the normal, bitangents and tangents should be multiplied by the normal matrix, which is indeed mat3(transpose(inverse(transform))) but I'm prepared to accept that's wrong, what should they be multiplied by? It works for my model loaded normals so didn't think it'd be any different

Comment: First: the normals itself: For the model you displayed, the nromals are seriously wrong. You should have a hard edge between discs at top bottom and the cylinder, you just smoothed the normals between both, which will result in really unplausible lighting.

Comment: Second, the orthogonality. The notation that the `TBN` vectors will be all orthonormal is a common _myth_.  Especially, the angles between `T` and `B` are defined by the actual 2d parametrization in texture space, and there is no requirement for a distortion-free mapping. This brings us to the third issue: the barycentric interpolation of vectors per fragment will not conserve the lenghts, so for the vectors to be normal, you have to re-normalize them.

Comment: Fourth: the inverseTranspose is only relevant for the normal, in order for it to remain orthogonal to the surface (whichever surface it was orthogonal to, initially.) However, the `T` and `B` vectors should lie in the plane of the actual surface, hence they must be transformed exactly as the surface itself.  Using the normal matrix here would move them out of the surface under non-uniform scaling conditions (and if no non-uniform scale applies, the relevant submatrix is orthogonal anyway)

Comment: However, I'm not sure if any of these issues completely explain your problem.

Comment: @derhass I have tried to implement each of your points but I'm struggling. I'm passing the TBN matrix down to the fragment shader, not each of the vectors, so what is it that would be affected by interpolation? Surely I can't normalize a matrix? 

I've tried multiplying the TBN vectors by just the transform matrix and I still get the same result.

 I've also attached a screenshot of the tangents, normals and bitangents mapped onto the cube, with arrows on the texture showing up and right.

Comment: instead of passing a matrix consisting of 3 vectors, you can simply pass 3 vectors, normalize them, and create a matrix as you see fit. But Fixing the length of those vectors will not make a significant change to the results you get,it just fixes a subtle error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
Actually nothing to do with the code above, although thanks to everyone that helped.

I was importing the texture using my own texture loader, which uses by default non-gamma corrected, SRGB colour in 32 bit. I switched it to 24bit and just RGB colour and it worked straight away. Typical developer problems....

[image: Before and After]